# Firebase not returning ID in useCollectionData

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a simple firebase to-do app. I can write todos, no problem. However, when I try to delete a todo or mark one as complete, it seems the `id` is `undefined`, and firebase can't find the to-do in question. How can I correct this? For context, I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuvP4h6O2x8&t=755s

Code:

```
import "../App.css";
import {useState} from "react";
import {auth, firestore} from "../firebase";
import firebase from "../firebase";
import {useCollectionData} from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";

const Todos = () => {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");
  const todosRef = firestore.collection(`users/${auth.currentUser.uid}/todos`);
  const [todos] = useCollectionData(todosRef, { idField: "id" });
  const signOut = () => auth.signOut();

  const onSubmitTodo = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTodo("");
    todosRef.add({
      text: todo,
      complete: false,
      createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <button onClick = {signOut}>Sign Out</button>
      </header>
      <main>
        <form onSubmit = {onSubmitTodo}>
          <input
            required
            value = {todo}
            onChange = {(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="what's next?"
            />
            <button type="submit"> Add </button>
        </form>
        {todos && todos.map((todo)=> <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} />)}
      </main>
    </>
  );
};


const Todo = ({ id, complete, text}) => {
  const todosRef = firestore.collection(`users/${auth.currentUser.uid}/todos`);
  const onCompleteTodo = (id, complete) =>
    todosRef.doc(id).set({ complete: !complete }, { merge: true });

  const onDeleteTodo = (id) => todosRef.doc(id).delete();

  return (
    <div key={id} className="todo">
      <button
        className={`todo-item ${complete ? "complete" : ""}`}
        tabIndex="0"
        onClick={()=> onCompleteTodo(id, complete)}
        >
          {text}
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => onDeleteTodo(id)}>x</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Todos;
```

Comment: What have you already done to troubleshoot the issue? You're using a library, have you already checked [useCollectionData](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/blob/master/firestore/README.md#usecollectiondata) documentation?

Comment: My first step was reviewing the documentation. I also diff'd my file with the code in the tutorial (nothing found there). Using console logs to log out the `id` value in the Todo function returned undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**React Firebase Hooks v5** matches **Firebase 9** and above, in which you should use the `FirestoreDataConverter` interface.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/blob/master/firestore/README.md#transforming-data).

The examples use TypeScript, but in your case something like this should work, applying `withConverter` and your custom converter right after getting the collection:

```js
const converter = {
    toFirestore(post) {
        return {
            text: post.text,
        }
    },
    fromFirestore(snapshot, options) {
        const data = snapshot.data(options)
        return {
            id: snapshot.id,
            text: data.text,
        }
    },
}

const todosRef = firestore
    .collection(`users/${auth.currentUser.uid}/todos`)
    .withConverter(converter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to rules and type edit with following code:

```
 allow read, write: if request.time>timestamp.date(2022, 11, 23);
```